# Setting R environment variable from a Shiny module using Sys.setenv()

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a shiny app with a module including a username/password input fields and save them to the environment variable through `Sys.setenv()`
A full example of what I have done is available [here](https://github.com/lyndametref/RBoilerplateShinyWithCredentials/tree/c6867402eb9b5e7d23a5cf8b848e440bc7ddf893)

In summary, I have created a module in setCredentials.R (set/get username and password are one line function using `Sys.getenv()` and `Sys.setenv()`, not displayed here for space sake)

```
credentialsInput <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    textInput(ns("username"), "Username", value = get_username()),
    passwordInput(ns("password"), "Password", value = get_password()),
    actionButton(ns("credentialSubmitButton"), "Submit" ))
}

setCredentials <- function(input, output, session){
  eventReactive(input$credentialSubmitButton,{
    set_username(input$username)
    set_password(input$password)
  })

  observeEvent(input$credentialSubmitButton,{
    print(paste(get_username(),get_password()))
  })
}
```

Then in my app.R file I have called the module

```
ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Set credentials"),
   credentialsInput("credentials")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  callModule(setCredentials,"credentials")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If variable are already set in the .Rprofile or equivalent, they are properly displayed in the field as default values. However if I modify (or enter in case of no .Rprofil) the print command return unchanged values (also if I click several times in case the print is executed before the set functions)

I guess somehow I cannot access the proper environment with `Sys.setenv()` from my module, but I don't understand exactly why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There must be a way to do this without adding dependencies, but I dealt with similar issues by using the `settings` package - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/settings/vignettes/settings.html - which works fine also in a shiny environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to have this working. In my `setCredentials` function, I need to set the username and password in a `observeEvent` function call rather than a `eventReactive`...

```
setCredentials <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$credentialSubmitButton,{
    set_username(input$username)
    set_password(input$password)

    print(paste(get_username(),get_password()))
  })
}
```